# Get Session Context from soap handler in Java

Tags: java, web-services, session, soap, handler

I'm trying to make some checkings around SOAPMessage inside a handler, and it works fine, but after that I need to pass certain results (2 boolean flags and 1 string) to WebService. I thought using that will be a good idea:

```
@Resource
private SessionContext ctx;
```

Yet I was wrong, since handler starts in a different context (or smth like that).
I tried doing as this article tells me http://gcmuganda.faculty.noctrl.edu/classes/Spring12/615/Lab4/CSC615Spring12MessageHandlersLab.html and got no result from that either.

Is there any way to actually pass that data to webservice without writing some absurd code?

Answer (score 0):

nevermind me, that link actually does it right.
Only thing I need to mention - don't add any other Context-like `@Resource` things in handler class.